# How to package Mongodb with a using npm require?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How do I package the Mongodb with a npm module mitigating the need to install MongoD,  automatically installing a mongodb database when running npm install?

Comment: You can consider using docker container and docker-compose.

Comment: add that module into package.json file.

Comment: It's not a module...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- Use an embedded javascript database with a mongodb like interface, such as [tingodb](http://www.tingodb.com/) or [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) (easy).
- Write a (shell) script that installs a MongoDB [binary](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production) and is run
  before or after npm install using the package.json scripts property,
  [see npm docs here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) (best).
- Fork [MongoDB](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo) and create an npm global package that [builds](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/building.md) and installs mongo (messy).